# Should we apply the same rules to question and answer pairs that we apply to questions?

Tags: discussion

Perhaps I'm mistaken but I've noticed by that by default the same level of moderation is applied to questions with answers added at the same that is applied to pure questions.
Resulting in them being closed.

The question taken alone my falsely give the impression of low effort.
But often on these cases the poster has taken a lot of time to craft a useful answer.
I feel that when these are moderated both the question and answer should be taken into account.

Personally I am willing to accept a lower quality question to benefit from a good quality answer.
I think in such cases rather than vote to close we should advise authors on how to edit to make things better instead.

Comment: I discourage "immediate" self-answering.

Comment: @NikeDattani write an answer post and explain why. You need to recognize that that position is against... a lot: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/997587 just to give two examples. I recognize that there are differences on specific sites (Puzzling and Code Review come to mind), but those exceptions always have good reasons. State your reasons. Let people vote.

Comment: @NikeDattani comments are not for answers. I see what you've stated as answer material. It's not so much an "order" as a suggestion. I can't order you to do anything.

Comment: This question is not about whether you should answer. stack exchange clearly supports self-answering itself as it provide direct UI support for it.

Comment: Just to reaffirm the above point see https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: "I think in such cases rather than vote to close we should advise authors on how to edit to make things better instead." The purpose of closing questions is to prevent answers from coming in. If the question is low quality, it should not solicit answers from the crowd. Just because the person asking *personally* understands the question well enough to answer it, doesn't mean other people should have to put up with the question as asked.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree that a question being self-answerable doesn't necessarily mean it's appropriate for the site (if that's what you're conveying). As for the "purpose of closing questions", I think preventing answers is one thing, but it's not the only purpose. Another purpose is to prevent people's time from being wasted.

Comment: I know you are talking about "other peoples time" but if you've been on the receiving end of the close hammer it has the complete opposite effect. There is little worse that spending time on crafting a question, specifically trying to meet the guidelies, and still being judged overly harshly. That is one aspect of what people mean when they accuse SO of being toxic.

Comment: @BruceAdams in many regards I totally agree with you. However when a user asks a question then never, ever visits the site again (ignores all comments asking for clarification, and has "last seen 1 year ago" on their profile), then on my favorite SE site we have a custom close reason called "abandoned question". This prevents people from having their time wasted and doesn't do much harm to the abandoned user. In terms of toxicity, I'm glad you mentioned it. But I found the comments and comment votes in this chain to be equally toxic; if you were on the receiving end, would you feel the same?

Comment: @NikeDattani my guess is you are referring to being "ordered to write an answer"? I think that was just the one comment where perhaps a please would have gone a long way. I didn't read the original comment as an order but perhaps I just mentally added a please when reading.

Comment: Abandoned question is an interesting idea but I don't think it works. A bad question will be voted to oblivion before a day is up never mind a year. A good question remains good even if it is abandoned. If it needs clarification its probably on the bad side.
The problem comes when you get many downvotes in a short time and there is no hope of recovery however much you edit.
Cf https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377207/why-is-this-question-about-magic-comments-in-go-still-considered-off-topic vs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487371/what-are-the-uses-of-semantic-comments-in-go

Answer (score 7):

Self-answered questions must meet the same standard as any other questions. An unclear question with a self-answer is still unclear; it will be difficult for others to write their own answers if they can't tell what the question is.

Of course it is always better if the author edits their question to fix it, rather than for the question to be closed. But closing the question may still be worthwhile because it saves other answerers from having to take the time to read it while it's not in an answerable state. Closing a question doesn't prevent the OP from editing to improve it, and once it's improved the question can be reopened. However, self-answer or not, I think it is often a good idea to first post a comment explaining the problem with the question, and wait a bit, and only vote to close after a bit of time if it's clear the OP isn't going to fix the question soon.

The effort put into a self-answer can at best indicate that the person asking the question has put research effort into it, but this research effort should also be demonstrated in the question. Lack of research effort usually just results in downvotes though, not necessarily close votes.

---

It's worth adding that this issue [has already been discussed extensively on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137353/1135948). From the top answers there:

> Part of the problem I see with self-answered questions is that people put so much effort into their answer that they forget the question has to be of acceptable quality as well. If the question is so bare-bones that it wouldn't be allowed as a standalone incoming question from the broader community, why does adding a giant detailed answer magically make it suddenly acceptable? It doesn't.
>
> ─[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137359/1135948)

> Let's treat these questions just like any other question. As a community, we need to train ourselves to hold these questions to the same standard we would any other question.
>
> ─[jmort253](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137369/1135948)

Comment: I'm particularly thinking of questions like those from @starball - for example https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-do-we-think-of-soft-meta-questions

Comment: The research effort dimension is a good demonstration of one of my points. Given an item of research do you put it in the question or the answer? My inclination is that it should be part of the answer. Duplication would be wasteful.

Comment: @BruceAdams related on that point, see also this on MSE: [Is a short description of a question OK if self-answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256644/997587) I've also updated my answer post here to quote from that.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I'm part of the motivation for this question given [the number of self-answered Q&A I've done recently](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/235/251).

[There was a certain point when I took a great interest in how users across various Stack Exchange sites view self-answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385418/997587). [I did a fair bit of reading meta posts across various sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385506/997587). One of the themes I found on network site meta discussions on the topic, is that for many sites, [including MSE, which is for discussing all network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297433/997587), self-answering does not give you a free pass on writing a good quality question.

See also [Monica Cellio's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256654/997587) to [Is a short description of a question OK if self-answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256644/997587) :

> The content (or authorship) of answers is not relevant in evaluating a question. Questions should stand alone. Not all questions have to be long, but they do have to be complete enough that the question would meet the site's standards (complete, on-topic, clear, etc) without any answers present.
>
> It can be more difficult to write a good self-answered question. You already *know* the answer, and that can affect how you ask the question. So it's good to take a little extra care on these to make sure you're not posting an insufficient question just to get to the answer.

I.e. There's generally some consensus that questions across Stack Exchange should meet all of what we expect of any question- self-answered or not. It should be clear and descriptive, reasonably well-scoped, on-topic, either objective or "good subjective", etc.

I'm no exception to that rule.

In my defense, I do try (already). Though I don't necessarily do a good job. So I appreciate feedback when my questions need improvement.

Use your close-votes (when close-reasons apply). [That's what they're for](/help/closed-questions). If you want to take an extra step, comment specific feedback on which parts of the question should be improved, and (a step further,) how.

Comment: It shouldn't give you a free pass but what tends to happen is the context and content of the answer is disregarded altogether. There is a happy medium to be found somewhere.

Comment: The context and content of the answer *should* be disregarded when evaluating the question. The same would apply if an unclear question were posted and immediately answered by someone else, and the OP indicated the answer was indeed what they were looking for ─ the identity of the person who wrote the answer should not matter when judging the quality of the question. Actually if the answer were written by someone else, that would be evidence *in favour* of the question being clear enough to be understandable and answerable. It being a self-answer is not likewise evidence of that.

Comment: @kaya3 ok... was there some part of this answer that contradicted that?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been a reply to @BruceAdams

Answer (score -1):

I found your question to be a little difficult to read.

Let me see if I can paraphrase:

> There are questions which have answers added at the same that the question is posted. There are also pure questions, with no answer provided by anyone (at first). It seem like moderators apply the same same attitude to both sorts of things, resulting in the questions being closed.
>
> Sometimes the question is badly written. However, there exist high quality answers to poor quality questions. I feel that when these questions are considered for deletion, the quality of question and answer together should be taken into account instead of the question only.
>
> Personally, I am willing to accept a lower quality question to benefit from a good quality answer. I think in such cases we should not vote to close the question. Instead, we should advise authors on how to edit the question make things easier to understand.

If we summarize your suggestion to be more concise than the original, then we have:

> In the past, questions were closed no matter if there are good quality answers or not.
>
> Poorly written questions which have high quality answers should not be deleted if there is a high quality answer to the question.

---

Some moderators will not be able to memorize dozens of highly specific rules for what questions get closed and which questions are not closed.

Your rule seems like a highly specific rule to me.

---

I suggest the following more general rule which might be easier for moderators to memorize:

> All questions are allowed, and no questions should be closed, unless one of the following conditions is satisfied:

## Reasons to Close and/or Delete a Question

| Condition No. | General Rule | Specific Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The question is rude or uses vulgar languages | Why do %$$#ls like to require languages be case-sensitive when they design their languages? |
| 2 | The question is about something other than designing programming languages | Do you like to eat pistachio ice-cream or cookie-dough ice-cream? |
| 3 | There is in insufficent storage space to store all of the questions | a question with more negative votes than any other question on the site which has zero answers and was posted more than 2 years ago |
| 4 | The question has been asked before | Two different people asked, "What is the difference between ***stdcall*** and the ***C-standard-calling convention***?" |

---

If you do not find a question interesting to you, you could find a different question you find more interesting. I hope that users of this web-forum will answer questions they enjoy rather than vote to close everything which does not fall within their particular expertise or past experience.

If you are not sufficiently knowledgeable about a particular sub-field of Programming Language Design, someone else probably is knowledgeable about it, and that other person could answer the question.

As a silly analogy, I find that some moderators on an imaginary stack exchange website about biological plants who were knowledgeable about trees would be highly likely vote to close all questions about annual flowers. Trees are not annual flowers, and some moderators don't care that such a forum would be about biological plants in general. Many of the moderators could leave content they do not personally enjoy alone instead of destroying it. Various search filters can be used to find things you like, such as `interpreters -compilers` will omit question about compilers and will show questions regarding interpreters.

Comment: You missed out several other common reasons to close including:

1. The question is unclear

2. The question shows insufficient research

Number 2 I think gives pause as the research is in the answer.